# Xamarin.Android + MVVMCross: DrawerLayout class conflict after upgrading to MVVMCross 6.3.1

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have Xamarin Android app that uses MVVMCross framework. My app targets Android 8.1

Now I'm upgrading MVVMCross NuGet packages from version 6.2.1 to version 6.3.1, and faced several problems, which lead to uncompilable state of code.

At first MVVMCross v.6.3.1 requires Android projects to target Android 9.0. Ok, I'm updated target framework property and android manifest to support 9.0 version. My app compiled and worked normally.

Next I've updated all MVVMCross NuGet packages to latest version 6.3.1. During update several new NuGet packages was added to my project. One of them was Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout. It was added because Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI package depends on it on Android 9.0.

All MVVMCross packages were updated successfully, but VisualStudio started to show error:

```
The type 'DrawerLayout' exists in both 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
and 'Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

in code:

```
public abstract class ViewWithMenuBase<T> : ViewBase<T> where T : ViewModelWithMenuBase
{
    protected override int? ToolbarButtonResourceId => Resource.Drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
    }
}
```

base class is defined as follows:

```
public abstract class ViewBase<T>: MvxAppCompatActivity<T> where T : class, IMvxViewModel
{
    ...
}
```

Now if I try to delete Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI or Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout errors in VisualStudio code editor disappears but app is not compiling due to erors about missing references on deleted package.

So, any idea how this error can be solved? Where I should look?

Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

Fully qualify which DrawerLayout you want to use by their namespace. One possible way to solve this is an `using` directive as followed:

```
using DrawerLayout = Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout.DrawerLayout;
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I've already tried this - not helps: type DrawerLayout has absolutely same namespace in both packages: Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout. There is no namespace Xamarin.Android.Support in any package

Comment: @Sergey Could you provide me with the package versions of Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI and Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI?

Comment: @Ramio, yes, of course. Both packages has 28.0.0.1 version

Comment: @Ramio, hello again. Do you have any suggestions?